# ShowCursor not working

Tags: windows, user32

i'm trying to write a simple C# win32 console app that uses ShowCursor (user32.dll) in order to hide the system mouse.
calling ShowCursor(false) returns -1 (as it should), but the mouse cursor remains. calling again with ShowCursor(true) returns 1 (but with no visible effect since the cursor never disappeared).

thanks.

Comment: forgot to mention - I'm using windows XP SP3.

Comment: see remarks in ShowCursor description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this method just increments the internal show counter

Answer (score 10):

`ShowCursor` affects the mouse when it is over a window that was created by your thread. Your console application probably did not create any windows, so `ShowCursor` has no effect.

Comment: To elaborate: You do not own the console window, so you cannot control the cursor of the console window.